# Executar método no servidor ao fechar o navegador

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethods

Preciso que ao usuário fechar o navegador ou a aba da pagina, atualizar o status Logado que está na base de dados(para controle de acessos do usuário).

Para isso utilize o seguinte

### Método `JavaScript`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    PageMethods.LogOut();
}
```

### E o seguinte `WebMethod`:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void LogOut()
{
     //Atualiza status do usuário
}
```

O problema é que esse método é chamado a todo instante, quando troco de página, quando atualizo a página(<kbd>F5</kbd>), como resolvo isso?

Comment: Talvez seja melhor trocar o evento para window.onclose = function(){}, mais infos neste [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose)

Comment: Já tentei com onclose, mas não funciona.

Comment: @GabrielSantosReis, o que você pode fazer é adicionar um listener no evento click dos `a` e dos `input:submit`, assim como no keypress para monitorar o `F5 (keycode: 116)`, caso algo assim ocorra você seta uma flag informando que `LogOut` não deve ser chamado... Infelizmente esta abordagem vai apenas minimizar o seu problema, pois um refresh manual (button do navegador) irá disparar o LogOut.

Comment: @TobyMosque, realmente o F5 é o menor dos meus problemas, isso me ajuda muito pouco.

Comment: Vi este [exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser), testei no jsfiddle e aparentemente funciona, menos quando vc fecha o browser todo....

Comment: Não é possivel detectar o fechamento de janelas com javascript, este evento detecta descarregamento que é diferente de fechamento, ou seja todo fechamento faz o unonload, mas nem todo unonload é proveniente de fechamentos, aqui eu expliquei bem como isto ocorre e em que momentos podemos usa-lo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635 --- Eu também mencionei sobre o uso do `window.popstate`, usando ele você poderia conseguir diferenciar paginação de alguns fechamentos

Answer (score 1):

Sei de uma forma para fazer o que você quer, mas consome deixa a aplicação mais pesada.

O conceito é basicamente o seguinte:

O usuário logado tem um script javascript sendo executado, setInterval, respondendo "chamada" para o servidor de tempos em tempos.

A cada 4 segundos, por exemplo, insere-se um registro na tabela usuario_activity com o ID do usuário e um datetime / timestamp atual.
*Antes da consulta, pode apagar os registros anteriormente inseridos, afinal só o que interessa é o insert mais recente do usuário.

O método que verifica se o usuário está online ou não busca na tabela usuario_activity a última vez que o usuário respondeu "presente" e verifica na mesma consulta com um DATE_DIFF se o tempo da última vez é superior a 4 segundos em relação à data atual, por exemplo.

OBS.: O tempo pode variar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Se necessário posso postar o código.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Protocolo HTTP 1.4 é por definição [não aguarda estado sobre conexão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) do cliente com o servidor, em resumo não há uma forma segura de garantir que um usuário de fato desconectou do seu servidor. Porém há técnicas que poderão te ajudar nessa tarefa.

Como nosso amigo Renan citou, talvez a mais conhecida e mais fácil seria o [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) onde o cliente consulta o servidor de tempos em tempos e você especifica um tempo entre requests limite para considerá-lo desconectado.

Também é possível você misturar esta técnica com o uso de websockets ou SSE.

Este problema será resolvido com o protocolo HTTP2.