# Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário que é um popup (div sobreposta)

```
<div class="bloco-newsletter" style="background-image: url(http://bhpump.izap.ws/plus/imggen/imageChangeColor/005873/bg-newsletter.png)">

    <div class="newsletter-title">NEWSLETTER</div>

    <form action="http://bhpump.izap.ws/plus/modulos/perfil/registrar_newsletter.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="op" value="register">

        <div class="text">Não saia ainda, temos ofertas exclusivas para você! Deixe seu e-mail aqui.</div>
                        <input class="ipt-newsletter" type="text" name="plus_email" value="" maxlength="60" data-placeholder="E-MAIL">


        <div class="btn-assinar">
            <img class="vermais_left pull-left" src="http://bhpump.izap.ws/plus/imggen/imageChangeColor/005873/btn-left-style.png" alt="">
            <input class="vermais_middle pull-left" style="background-color: #005873" name="ok" type="submit" value="ASSINAR">
            <img class="vermais_right pull-left" src="http://bhpump.izap.ws/plus/imggen/imageChangeColor/005873/btn-right-style.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Este form está oculto, quero quando tentar fechar a janela abrir este form   e só fechar a janela se clicar no submit  ou fechar o popup

Tentei isso mais a janela e fechada:

```
global $xTema;
$xTema->addJSOnReady('
$(window).unload(function(){
$("#modal_24").modal("show");
});
');
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107017/como-impedir-que-o-usu%C3%A1rio-feche-uma-p%C3%A1gina-sem-enviar-o-formul%C3%A1rio-por%C3%A9m-sem-u/107215#107215)

Comment: O evento correto é o unonload.

Comment: @WalkerLeite Mais eu só quero mostrar uma janela igual essa de confirmação, e tipo substituir ela

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Capturar evento fechar janela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108941/capturar-evento-fechar-janela)

Comment: Talvez [isso possa ter dar uma ideia](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87110/20615)

Comment: @DanielOmine não é bem uma duplicata, o problema que ele quer disparar um Modal semelhante ao do bootstrap no momento de tentar fechar, a situação vai além. É melhor fechar como erro de digitação (devido ele ter chamado um método que não existe).

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento, a pergunta é diferente mas a resposta é a mesma.  Sobre a ação após bloquear o fechamento, seria questão secundária.

Comment: @DanielOmine não estou falando da pergunta, a resolução é diferente, lá não fala que elementos DOM não são disparados após o `unonload`, lá é apenas uma explicação de como capturar o "evento". Aqui a pergunta é sobre exibir um modal que é HTML (DOM) e a resposta aqui explica o porque não funciona. Tanto a pergunta é diferente, como a resposta não cobre a situação, espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: mas é exatamente essa a cerne da questão... sabendo fazer isso, conseguirá prosseguir com o restante.. por isso considero duplicata

Comment: @DanielOmine tudo bem, ele aprendeu a capturar o evento, legal, mas ele vai manipular o DOM e pronto não funciona após o `onbeforeunload`, porque haverá uma trava, o que ele quer não é isso, ele quer exibir um formulário pra assinar uma newsletter, a solução na outra resposta é só pra perguntar se o cara quer mesmo sair da página, `$("#modal_24").modal("show");` nunca irá funciona no `onbeforeunload`, só se o usuário clicar em ficar na página, mas ele pede aqui que seja se o usuário for sair e isso na outra resposta não explica. Então a pergunta aqui é mais ampla que a outra :)

Comment: exacerbado...  alem do mais quem deveria estar esclarecendo deveria ser o autor da pergunta..  rsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine a pergunta pode estar ruim da maneira que foi escrita, mas pelo código é possível perceber o que ele esperava que o script fizesse. Todavia se fosse pra fechar deveria cair mais como "erro de digitação" do que duplicata. Ele pediu rodar script, ou seja um script especifico e não prevenir o fechamento em si. (ps. use sempre o `@...` porque senão a mensagem não chega a quem você deseja enviar, só se a postagem for dele)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mesmo que você use `unload` ou `beforeunload` o formulário nunca vai ser exibido, isto é porque não tem como prevenir isto, o uso do `unload` é voltado para pequenas ações, como por exemplo destruir `cookies` ou `sessionStorage`, leia esta resposta:

[Jquery beforeunload é chamado quando clico em link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635)

No momento que o evento é executado a página já começou a ser "destruída" (leia sobre destruct e GUI em aplicações C/C++ ou C# para entender como funciona as GUIs em sistemas operacionais).

Também entenda que os eventos `unload` e `beforeunload` não são chamados apenas no fechar janela, mas qualquer página que fizer ele vai se executado, pois o evento não se chama `onCloseWindow` (esse evento nem existe), ele se chama `onunload`, traduzindo `unload` seria como "descarregar", ou seja a página carrega será descarregada (ou destruída), a cada paginação, fechamento de aba ou janela o evento é disparado, ou seja usar estes eventos para chamar formulários é uma péssima ideia em todos sentidos, além de muito difícil de implementar (ou seria impossível).

Recomendo que analise qual a necessidade deste formulário e veja se este é realmente o melhor caminho.

Ainda sim se quiser mesmo fazer da maneira que esta (que eu pessoalmente acho uma péssima experiencia para o usuário) você deve tentar usar o `beforeunload` com com `return`. Veja esta minha resposta:

[Enviar mensagem para navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91499/3635)

O código deve ficar algo como:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
    event.preventDefault();

    //Para customizar o texto, e é necessário para funcionar no Safari e Chrome, IE e Firefox anterior a versão 4
    event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Esse é o máximo que você vai conseguir impedir o fechamento, se o usuário aceitar, se não, <s>in</s>felizmente não tem como obrigar ou controlar o navegador do usuário, o navegador é dele e se ele quiser fechar tudo não tem o que fazer, levando em consideração que é muito chato algumas limitações que são colocadas em páginas web que só fazem o usuário querer evitar certos sites.

---

### Como alguns site conseguem fazer isso, como o facebook?

Então fui testar, algumas pessoas me disseram que no facebook aparecia um modal customizado quando fechava a janela, mas na verdade isso é uma impressão errada do que ocorre, na verdade quando clicamos em fechar aba ou navegador a tela que aparece é esta (se o campo texto ou comentário tiver com uma mensagem não enviada):

[image: Evento beforeunload no facebook]

Aquele modal customizado aparece quando clicamos em links dentro do site aonde o script esta sendo executado graças ao `window.onpopstate`, ou seja só ocorre se clicar e links dentro do site e não se fechar a página, veja que aqui preenchi o campo "status" do facebook e tentei clicar no link de um outro perfil, a imagem que me apareceu foi esta:

[image: Mensagem facebook window.onpopstate]

Então na verdade é um engano e é impossível customizar o popup/modal do `beforeunload`, pois se não poderíamos controlar os eventos sem solicitar ao usuário o que seria basicamente você controlar as ações do usuário (e isso ninguém quer né).

Comment: E até bom que não consiga controlar. Pois se eu entrar num site de alguém que fez isso comigo, nunca mais volto

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Exatamente este é um dos motivos, o outro é que o evento na verdade não detecta fechamento de página, mas sim descarregamento, claro que quando fechamos uma página ela descarrega naturalmente, mas é um efeito natural, assim como clicar em um link ou digitar um novo endereço, será necessário descarregar para carregar o novo conteudo ;)

Comment: Eu preciso saber como pegar a opção escolhida como "Sair da Página", no meu caso tenho que fazer umas verificações e excluir uns cookies e fazer uma chamada ajax antes da saída final.

Comment: @franzisk isso que você deseja é TOTALMENTE passível de problemas, como eu expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635, então a unica solução eficiente é usar um temporizador no back-end para "eliminar" o que ficou muito tempo OCIOSO. ps: se fosse possivel fazer de forma eficiente ao fechar a janela o googleanalytics usaria isto, mas não usa, tanto que respondi detalhadamente uma pergunta sobre o mesmo assunto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70316/3635

Comment: Entendi @GuilhermeNascimento, nesse caso tenho um problema real para controlar isso, uma vez que a autenticação é simples, portanto não tem um token com tempo de vida e tal, e o problema mesmo é que é de vital importância controlar a saída do usuário do sistema, no caso o back-end se trata de um sistema Java Spring-Boot. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual a versão que você está usando do jQuery, mas a função [**`unload()`**](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) está *deprecated* desde a versão ***1.8***. Você pode utilizar a função [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e esperar pelo evento **`unload`**.

```
$(window).on('unload',function(){
  $("#modal_24").modal("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A escuta **[unload](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_unload.asp)** já está [deprecated](http://www.guj.com.br/t/o-que-quer-dizer-um-metodo-deprecated/73266) (foi removido na versão 3.0+ do JQuery), o método mais recomendável é o **[unbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)** que ocorre quando você pressiona F5, CTRL+F5, clica em um hiperlink ou qualquer elemento que com javascript redireciona para outra página, envio de formulários e etc.

Importante lembrar que como o @Guilherme Nascimento mencionou, que no unbeforeunload/unload você não pode rodar qualquer javascript, alguns como alert("Hellow Wolrd") ou chamadas que abrem janelas window.open("http://minhaurl","minhaid","minhasconfigs"), redirecionamentos e etc são bloqueados pelos navegadores. Ele tem utilidade para por exemplo (como já mencionado): destruir cookies ou sessionStorage.

De fato, não existe uma maneira simples e única de escutar o "fechamento" (window being close) de uma janela mas eu passei por uma situação onde eu necessitava desta funcionalidade e segui os passos do código abaixo.

(O código abaixo é uma funcionalidade para limpar a sessão de um usuário logado pós fechamento de uma janela, ele também pode ser adaptado para demais funcionalidades que sejam permitidas pelos navegadores).

Segue o código testado e rodado em Chrome 67+ e Firefox 61+:

```
var wrapper = function () {

var deslogarUsuario = true;

 //Se o usuário está "focando" a janela, não há motivos para crer 
//que ele pretende fechar a mesma (oposto de blur)
$(window).on('focus', function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;  
});

$(window).on('blur', function () {

    $(window).off('resize'); //evita listening múltiplos e desnecessários
    deslogarUsuario = true;
    //quando o usuário está minimizando a janela
    if (!document.hidden) {
        deslogarUsuario = false;
    }
    //quando o usuário está maximizando a janela
    $(window).on('resize', function (e) {
        deslogarUsuario = false;
    });

});

//Quando o usuário está deixando a página html, nos dá mais razões para 
//acreditar que ele pretende fechar a janela (com o mouse)
$('html').on('mouseleave', function () {
    deslogarUsuario = true;
});

//Quando o usuário está entrando na página, nos dá menos razões para 
//acreditar que ele pretenda fechar a janela (com o mouse)
$('html').on('mouseenter', function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;
});

//Estas escutas são essenciais, pois F5 e CTRL+F5 também acionam o evento 
//onbeforeunload, você também pode tentar escutar por eventos como ALT+F4 
//mas este mesmo não terá o mesmo efeito, pois é primeiramente escutado pelo 
//navegador e efetuado a ação padrão (fechar)
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 91 || e.keyCode == 18 && !blurOnPage) {
        deslogarUsuario = false;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 116 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82)) {

        deslogarUsuario = false;
    }
});

//Evita que hiperlinks acionem a função no onbeforeunload
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;
});

//Evita que botões acionem a função no onbeforeunload (útil para aqueles que 
//contiverem javascripts que redirecionam ou recarregam a página)
$(document).on("click", "button", function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;

});

//Evita os submits de formulários
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;
});

//Evita os input[type="submit"] de formulários
$(document).on("click", "input[type=submit]", function () {
    deslogarUsuario = false;
});

//Função que pode ser utilizada ou adaptada para quando ocorrer fechamento 
//da janela
var derrubaUsuario = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MeuController/MinhaActionLogOut',
        async: false,
        data: {

        },
        error: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
        },
    });
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {

    console.log('teste');
    if (deslogarUsuario) {
        derrubaUsuario();
    }
};
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da versão mas eu normalmente uso a função `unload()`

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
      //Seu codigo
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando o usuário tenta sair da página por qualquer razão, o evento `beforeUnload` é disparado.

Por exemplo, quando tentar submeter um `form`, clicar em um `link`, fechar uma `window` (`tab`) etc.

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    // seu código 
});
```

**Fonte:** [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)