# Capturar evento fechar janela

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso executar uma ação quando o usuário fechar uma janela no meu sistema PHP. Encontrei um código JS que faz isso no IE, mas no Firefox não funciona:

```
    document.onkeydown = fecharIE;
    window.onbeforeunload = fecharIE;
    //for IE
    function fecharIE (evt){
         var iX = window.document.body.offsetWidth - window.event.clientX ;
         var iY = window.event.clientY ;
        if (iX <=30 && iY < 0){
           // quando botão de fechar da janela é acionado
           sair();
        }

        if (!evt)
            evt = event;
        if (event.altKey && event.keyCode==115){
         //ALT+F4
          sair();
        }
    }
```

Alguém tem a solução para o Firefox?

Comment: Aqui usamos `firefox` e sempre funciona com `onbeforeunload` e `onunload`.

Comment: Dessa mesma forma que está no código postado?

Comment: Na verdade usamos direto `window.onunload = function(e){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo funciona bem nos navegadores atuais:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "Tem certeza que quer fechar?"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: funciona perfeitamente..Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! Outra forma de fazer isso é fazendo:

```
<script>
  var script = function() {
    //Faço qualquer coisa que eu precise
    return 'Retorno que aparece na tela';
  }
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", script);
</script>
```

Esse "//Retorno que aparece na tela" aparece quando você clica para sair da página e ele mostra uma mensagem (String que esta sendo retornada) e pergunta "Sair da página" ou "Continuar na página".