# Como exibir uma modal no beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Com o evento `beforeunload`, eu posso exibir uma mensagem quando a página está para ser cancelada ou atualizada.

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
     return 'Testando';
 });
```

Porém o cliente para quem costumo desenvolver os sistemas não gostam muitos dos layouts do `alert`, `confirm` ou `prompt` do javascript.

Então eu gostaria de, nesse evento de `beforeunload`, colocar uma modal exibindo uma mensagem, no lugar daquele `alert` que aparece.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso ? Há alguma maneira de usar o evento `beforeunload`, sem colocar a mensagem de `alert`?

Comment: Não tem como aqui eu explico o porque [Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635)

Comment: Não é possível, aqui tem uma breve explicação [jQuery beforeunload custom pop up window for leaving a page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32018719/4763709)