# Função OnUnload JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a função `OnUnload` do javascript, porém não consigo encontrar erro. O `alert` deveria ser exibido antes de fechar o navegador, a janela ou carregar outra barra de endereços, correto?

```
function close(){
  alert("Não vá embora, inscreva-se...");
}

<body onunload="close()">
  <input type="button" value="Aula JS - Eventos" onclick="clique()"></input>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="txt_aula" onfocus="entra()" onblur="sai()"></input>
</body>
```

Alguém sabe se essa função ainda funciona no javascript?

Answer (score 2):

O `onunload` não é bem para disparar `alert();` é para disparar eventos como limpar cookies ou coisas do gênero, o que você quer é o `onbeforeunload`, faça assim:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Não vá embora, inscreva-se...";
};
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Aula JS - Eventos" onclick="clique()">
<br>
<input type="text" name="txt_aula" onfocus="entra()" onblur="sai()">
```

> Note que:
>
> - O `beforeunload` não mostra um `alert` e sim uma janela de confirmação, ou seja é o usuário quem decide
> - Esse evento não serve para detectar fechamento de janelas, a unica maneira de fazer isto é combinar o `beforeunload` com `window.onpopstate`
> - **Não é possível customizar** essa janela, veja os motivos aqui:
> - [Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635)

Uma dica extra:

- A tag `</input>` "não existe", na verdade elementos como `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<img>` e `<input>` [não tem tags de fechamento](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.3), se usar HTML faça simplesmente assim:

  ```
  <input type="button" value="Aula JS - Eventos" onclick="clique()">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="txt_aula" onfocus="entra()" onblur="sai()">
  ```
- Se usar XHTML faça assim:

  ```
  <input type="button" value="Aula JS - Eventos" onclick="clique()" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="txt_aula" onfocus="entra()" onblur="sai()" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja exibir alerta antes do Usuário deixar a página, utilize onbeforeunload.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = close;

function close(){
  return "Não vá embora, inscreva-se...";
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="button" value="Aula JS - Eventos" onclick="clique()"></input>
<br>
<input type="text" name="txt_aula" onfocus="entra()" onblur="sai()"></input>
```