# Como fazer para o alerta nativo do evento beforeunload não aparecer no navegador google chrome?

Tags: javascript, angular-8

Estou precisando bloquear o alerta nativo do navegador, a ideia é que apareça um modal no lugar, mas não estou conseguindo bloquear a ação:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onbeforeunload(event) {
  if (!this.isSaved) {
     this.openModal();
     event.preventDefault();
     event.returnValue = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Não é possível https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635